# Simplest way to change listview and treeview colours

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

I'm trying to find a simple way to change the colour of the text and background in `listview` and `treeview` controls in WTL or plain Win32 code.

I really don't want to have to implement full owner drawing for these controls, simply change the colours used.

I want to make sure that the images are still drawn with proper transparency.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following macros:

[ListView_SetBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775063%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[ListView_SetTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775116%28VS.85%29.aspx>)

[TreeView_SetBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760036%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[TreeView_SetTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760131%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There are also appropriate methods of the `CListViewCtrl` and `CTreeViewCtrl` wrapper classes:

- GetBkColor
- SetBkColor

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to take a look at WTL's CCustomDraw::OnItemPrePaint (that's if you need to control the drawing of individual items)

A good article that describes this process is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/WTL_TreeCtrl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've use the win32 API directly, but I believe that if you handle the WM_ERASEBACKGROUND message for your control, you can use FillRect() in your handler to paint the background using whatever color you like.